# How to plot error ellipses from covariance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I fitted my data with some parameters and now I have their optimal values `popt` and their covariance matrix `pcov`. I assume that these uncertainties are Gaussian and I would like to have a plot of error ellipses like the one below. Is there some easy way to do it (without manually doing every subplot)? I was looking at `pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix` which seems somehow close but I do not know ho to apply this to my multivariate Gaussian.

[image]

Comment: please provide small reproducible code

Comment: this plot is not mine (I found it somewhere) -- this is what I want to achieve, I`m looking for such a code

Comment: This may be a misunderstanding. SO is not a code writing service. Assuming you have already tried something you should tell what it is in form of linking to other questions which have not helped and providing a [mcve] of the failed attempt. See [ask]. Also the [SO checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) may help.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me but rather to point me in some right direction. I spend some time looking for something and the closets thing is the `pandas` package I mentioned. But because I never work with it I'm not sure if what I`m trying to achieve is something already written in the package or not. I assumed that more experienced users can tell me if it easy or not -- which is my question.

Comment: There is no magic `plot_my_errorellipses_from_data_to_grid` function. So should this be closed as "too broad" or as "off-topic (because of asking for software recommendations)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [corner.py](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py) package, documentation [here](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which does what I needed.

Simple example:

```py
import corner
import numpy as np

ndim, nsamples = 2, 10000
np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])
figure = corner.corner(samples)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) you can try making a [PairGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html) or using the [pairplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html) function. PairGrid is more flexible, whereas pairplot() is a quick way to look at some data with a default scatter matrix.